# Drawing Normals to Surfaces

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw the normal vectors to a mesh file so I can see how the normal vectors bounce from their respected face. In the draw function, it takes in each face and draws a line from the center point of the face to the (center + normal vector). When I run it, however, I do not see any red lines bouncing off each face. What am I doing wrong here?

```
void drawTria(myFace face) {

   glNormal3f((face.getNormal().x), (face.getNormal().y), (face.getNormal().z));
    wired ? glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP) : glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(vertexList.at(face.v1-1).x, vertexList.at(face.v1-1).y, vertexList.at(face.v1-1).z);
    glVertex3f(vertexList.at(face.v2-1).x, vertexList.at(face.v2-1).y, vertexList.at(face.v2-1).z);
    glVertex3f(vertexList.at(face.v3-1).x, vertexList.at(face.v3-1).y, vertexList.at(face.v3-1).z);
    glEnd();


    // Drawing normals
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(face.getCenter().x, face.getCenter().y, face.getCenter().z);
    glVertex3f((face.getCenter().x+face.getNormal().x), (face.getCenter().y+face.getNormal().y), (face.getCenter().z+face.getNormal().z));
    glEnd();

}

myVertex myFace::getCenter() {
    myVertex center;

    center.x = (vertexList.at(v1-1).x + vertexList.at(v2-1).x + vertexList.at(v3-1).x)/3;
    center.y = (vertexList.at(v1-1).y + vertexList.at(v2-1).y + vertexList.at(v3-1).y)/3;
    center.z = (vertexList.at(v1-1).z + vertexList.at(v2-1).z + vertexList.at(v3-1).z)/3;

    return center;
}

myVertex myFace::getNormal() {
    myVertex normal;

    normal.x = ((vertexList.at(v2-1).y - vertexList.at(v1-1).y)
                        * (vertexList.at(v3-1).z - vertexList.at(v1-1).z))
                        - ((vertexList.at(v2-1).z - vertexList.at(v1-1).z)
                            * (vertexList.at(v3-1).y - vertexList.at(v1-1).y));

    normal.y = ((vertexList.at(v2-1).z - vertexList.at(v1-1).z)
                        * (vertexList.at(v3-1).x - vertexList.at(v1-1).x))
                        - ((vertexList.at(v2-1).x - vertexList.at(v1-1).x)
                            * (vertexList.at(v3-1).z - vertexList.at(v1-1).z));

    normal.z = ((vertexList.at(v2-1).x - vertexList.at(v1-1).x)
                        * (vertexList.at(v3-1).y - vertexList.at(v1-1).y))
                        - ((vertexList.at(v2-1).y - vertexList.at(v1-1).y)
                            * (vertexList.at(v3-1).x - vertexList.at(v1-1).x));

    return normal;
}
```

Comment: Create a "model" consisting of a single triangle (0,0)(1,0)(0,1) and make sure your normal is the expected (0,0,1) and your center point is appropriate.

Comment: You could also consider simplifying your code. It is difficult to read, and performs far too many operations for your simple task - like do not call getCenter 6 times when only one is needed, etc.

Comment: Like genpfault said, reduce it down to simpler problems: does getNormal() produce the right answer for a simple case? does getCenter()? You could also print out the vertices under `// drawing normals` and see whether the first point is the same as the second point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the normals could also be pointing in the wrong direction -- for instance if the orientation of the triangles is reversed than the normal could be going into your drawn object.  Also, since your normal here isn't normalized (made unit length) it might be difficult to see esp. if your triangles are small.